# Multiple unique columns in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm creating a new form in SharePoint with the following fields:

1. Name
2. Phone
3. Email

But, I need that every column in the list is unique, it can't be any row with the same information.

I have an idea how to do this with javascipt, but don't know how to access to do a query in sharepoint to see if there is the same information.

If someone could help me with any solution would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I need that every column in the list is unique,

Are you saying that only one row in the list can have a certain email address? If so, just set "Enforce unique values:" for that column to "Yes". (Repeat for each column.)

Comment: I need the whole row to be unique, with all the fields (Name, phone and email), with "enforece unique values" can I do that?

Comment: Not sure that there is an out of the box way to do this. To get all of the column in one place to do that test you would need a Calculated Column, but they don't have the "unique values" option. The only way I can think of without something like a custom event receiver would be a workflow. Are you using SharePoint 2013 or later? If so, you could have the workflow make a web service call to check for a duplicate. This would not be real time, i.e. stop the save of the item. It could only change one of the columns or send an email.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a column value like Email to be unique you can use the "Enforce Unique values" from the columns settings like shown below.
[image]

However if you want multiple columns to be unique like a composite unique key you will have override the presaveaction in the page to do a check before inserting the record. you can get more details of the presave action in the below link.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/what-is-the-difference-between-presaveaction-and-presaveitem-on-sharepoint-l

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx